# Minimum number of books to fulfill a condition

Tags: combinatorics, extremal-combinatorics

There is a group of 100 Readers who come together every month to discuss their findings from the books they have read. They discuss in a group of two people. In order to start a discussion between two people, each individual should have read at least one book that the other person hasn't.

What is the minimum number of distinct books (across all people) that are needed to achieve the condition for any two random members of the group to start a discussion?

Comment: Just a thought, but could we compare this to binary numbers? If there are $n$ books, let each reader has a binary code that is $n$ digits long. 1 means that they have read it and 0 means that they haven't read it ... Then the condition becomes that the binary code must be different for everyone.

Comment: I think the problem needs clarification. If we have two people and one book, is it possible to achieve this condition? I mean the part "**each** individual should have read at least one book that the other person hasn't" - does this mean that both of them have to have read a book that the other one hasn't?

Comment: Suppose there  are 9 books and everyone has a different set of 4 that they have read. That works for up to 126 people.

Comment: @almagest I like that idea, but how do you prove that $8$ is not enough?

Comment: I can't see any random element in the problem. Perhaps you mean "arbitrary" where you wrote "random"?

Comment: @almagest...can u elaborate please...some sort of solution

Comment: @StinkingBishop See  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sperner%27s_theorem#Statement

Answer (score 5):

As suggested by Almagest, we need $9$ books, with a different subset of $4$ assigned to each reader.  There are $\binom{9}{4} = 126$ subsets, so that is a feasible setup for up to $126$ readers.  If we had only $8$ books, the largest number of readers we could assign in this way is $\binom{8}{4} = 70$.

That $\binom{9}{4}$ is the largest number of subsets of $9$ objects in which no subset is a subset of another is a consequence of [Sperner's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sperner%27s_theorem): the largest number of subsets of $n$ objects in which no subset is a subset of another is
$$\binom{n}{\lfloor n / 2 \rfloor}$$